# SQL Transactions Error: Can't update table 'todo' in stored function/trigger because it is already used

Tags: sql, t-sql, yii

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_todo;")->execute();
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CREATE TRIGGER update_todo AFTER DELETE ON user_todo_send FOR EACH ROW BEGIN "
        . " UPDATE todo SET status = 1 WHERE id = OLD.id_todo; END;")->execute();
```

In response, I receive an error :

> Can't update table 'todo' in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger..

Comment: First, you have tagged the question "tsql" and then used MySQL syntax.  Please tag the question appropriately.  Second, do you get the error when you *run* the trigger or when you *create* it?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you are really using MySQL.  Use an *after* delete trigger.  Using your syntax, that would look like this (and I assume you have the right `delimiter` statements:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_todo`;
CREATE TRIGGER `update_todo` AFTER DELETE ON `user_todo_send` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `todo`
        SET status = 1
        WHERE id IN (SELECT OLD.id_todo 
                     FROM user_todo_send 
                     WHERE OLD.id_todo = todo.id
                    );
END;
```

This is really simpler to write as:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_todo`;
CREATE TRIGGER `update_todo` AFTER DELETE ON `user_todo_send` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `todo`
        SET status = 1
        WHERE id = OLD.id_todo
END;
```

Or, forget triggers altogether and add a cascading delete foreign key reference.